# Why isn't Google Maps changing zoom when asked to do so?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got this bit of code here:

```
function ShowSelection(addr){
    var latLngBounds;

    geocoder.geocode({ "address": addr }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            if (selectionArea === undefined || selectionArea === null) {
                selectionArea = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                    map: map
                });
            }

            latLngBounds = results[0].geometry.bounds;
            selectionArea.setBounds(latLngBounds);

            map.panTo(latLngBounds.getCenter());
            map.setZoom(12);
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that when I call map.setZoom(12) the map just stays at the same zoom level it was already at.

I guess a better solution would be to set it to a zoom level that shows the full selectionArea in the map window.

So I guess this is sort of a double question:

1. How do I get the zoom level to change when calling setZoom()?
2. How would I set the zoom level so that a Rectangle drawn on the map would completely fit in the bounds of the map div? (The desired effect I'm looking for is to have the map pan to the center point of the selectionArea and have the bounds of the map be larger than the bounds of the selection area i.e. the whole selectionArea is visible on the map w/o scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your problem.
The code you posted geocodes an address and draws a rectangle with the same size of the map bounds.
So...

> How do I get the zoom level to change
>   when calling setZoom()?

well... it seems ok. Check if your map zoom isn't already set at 12

> How would I set the zoom level so that
>   a Rectangle drawn on the map would
>   completely fit in the bounds of the
>   map div?

You can make map fits the bounds with

```
map.fitBounds(latLngBounds);
```

Comment: yep, I've confirmed that I'm zoomed out to zoom 4 when I clicked the button that fires the event in my code snippet. That map.setZoom() call isn't doing a darn thing that I can tell.

Comment: @Ryan i've tested `setZoom()` on jsfiddle it works fine the way you call it.  did you set the bound limit or something?

Comment: here is a link to a working js-fiddle of my code to get the undesired effect (of not zooming) you type in a zip code or city/state combo into the search box in the upper left and click the button that says "Center". You'll see that the pan takes place but the zoom doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/pbwfL/1/

Comment: @Ryan You wrote `if (map != null) google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(map)` in the ClearSelection function thus removing the zoom_changed listener as well.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for the time you put into helping me with this. I thought that calling the clearInstanceListeners method would only remove any custom listeners I put on the object. Nice to know.